# Uninstall Python 3.4 from Debian 7.5 "Wheezy"

Tags: python, debian, uninstallation, python-3.4

I recently installed Python 3.4.1 (GCC 4.7.2) on Debian 7.5 (amd64) by compiling it from source files (Python-3.4.1.tgz).

I now want to remove it, but doing "apt-get remove python3.4" isn't really helping.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you installed your compiled-from-source Python systemwide (using `sudo` and not setting a `PREFIX` variable), then the following should overwrite your install with the standard Debian version:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall python3
```

Since Wheezy doesn't appear to have a *python3.4* package (instead using 3.2 as its default Python 3), you should then be able to safely remove any files and folders relating to Python 3.4. I'm guessing to an extent here, based on what's on my Ubuntu machine with a local (non-system) source install of Python 3.4, but those files and folders should be something like:

**folders**:

- /usr/lib/python3.4
- /usr/include/python3.4m

**files**:

- /usr/bin/python3.4
- /usr/bin/python3.4-config
- /usr/bin/python3.4m
- /usr/bin/python3.4m-config
- /usr/lib/libpython3.4m.a
- /usr/lib/pkgconfig/python-3.4m.pc
- /usr/lib/pkgconfig/python-3.4.pc
- /usr/share/man/man1/python3.4.1

Comment: Thanks Zero Piraeus, I will try that out. Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Zero Piraeus, I tried   `code`apt-get install --reinstall python3`code`  but get the error:  Invalid operation python3  Should i manually remove all the relevant Python-3.4.1 from the folders?